# whats the difference between built in android applications and user application

Tags: android

I am working on application which needs to auto answer the call . but due to security issues I am unable to acheive it form my app , but I can do it through android's Phone applications,
can anybody tell me that how android differentiate its built in apps and user apps..??

do it uses any certificate to diffretiate....???

Comment: Have you tried setting the proper permissions?

Comment: Paste your permission settings from you manifest file. It may be easier to debug you app then.

Comment: Hi these are the permissions that i set in manifest file.........  "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED"
"android.permission.CALL_PHONE"
"android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
"android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, third party applications can't do this.  This isn't just a matter of permissions -- supporting such a thing requires work to provide a UI for the user to determine and manage what apps can do this, and no such thing has been written at this point.